# Remove the space break between chapters

Tags: page-breaking

I am working with a book environment, I would like to know how eliminate the blank space between chapters in my tesis.

Could anyone help me with it?

```
% ===== INICIO DEL PREÁMBULO =====
%
\documentclass[psg,oneside,a4paper]{udelar} % Poner msc para Maestría, dsc para Doctorado.
%
\usepackage[
acronyms,                                            %utiliza el glosario de acronimos.
nohypertypes={acronym,notacion,simbolos,glosario},   %quita los links en el texto al glosario.
%nonumberlist,                                       %quita los links en los glosarios al texto.
nogroupskip,                                         %quita los espacios entre diferentes grupos dentro de un glosario.
nopostdot,                                           %quita el punto final en los acrónimos         .                           
]{glossaries}

\hypersetup{ colorlinks = true } % Hipervínculos: escribir "false" para imprimir o "true" para ver en digital.

% Ver los documentos de estilos bibliográficos para editar estas siguientes 2 líneas. Se deben de copiar a partir de los PDF de estilos bibliográficos y no es necesario que el estudiante las edite.
\usepackage{natbib} % Para algunos estilos bibliográficos
\bibliographystyle{estilos_bibliograficos/natbib/apalike}

\loadglossary % No comentar esta línea

% A su vez, la clase udelar.cls ya tiene los siguientes paquetes cargados automáticamente, que podrían ser de interés saber para el usuario:
% 
% {color},{hyphenat},{appendix},{lastpage},{babel},{inputenc},{amsmath,amssymb},{ifthen},{graphicx},{caption}
% {setspace},{tabularx},{eqparbox},{ltxcmds},{titletoc},{xcolor},{lineno},{xwatermark}

% Si se quieren agregar más paquetes, se recomienda colocarlos a partir de esta linea y antes de \begin{document}.
% ===========  INICIO PAQUETES ===============
\usepackage{siunitx}% paquete para manejo de números y unidades
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\chapfnt}{\fontsize{16}{16}}
\newcommand{\secfnt}{\fontsize{12}{12}}
\newcommand{\ssecfnt}{\fontsize{12}{12}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\chapfnt\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{10pt}{\chapfnt}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\secfnt\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\ssecfnt\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{5pt}{5pt}
\titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{1ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection} {0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\usepackage{times}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\def\UrlFont{\normalfont}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-weight, detect-display-math}
\sisetup{detect-inline-weight=math}
\sisetup{mode=text,per-mode=symbol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\newlength\fwidth
\setlength{\fwidth}{0.8\textwidth}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\usepackage{overpic}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{bicaption}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{subcaption}

% ===========   FIN PAQUETES   ===============

% Definición de correctores, con un máximo de tres correctores.
\definechangesauthor[color=redtex]{JLM}         % Siglas del primer corrector 
\definechangesauthor[color=bluetex]{JH}         % Siglas del segundo corrector
\definechangesauthor[color=greentex]{MC}        % Siglas del tercer corrector

% =====  FIN DEL PREÁMBULO  =====

% ===== INICIO DEL DOCUMENTO =====

\begin{document}
  %
  \title{}
  \institutelogo{1} % Carga cantidad de logos seleccionados, con máximo de 3 logos.
  \author{}{}
  \escritura{en} % Se indica que el programa de Posgrado sea "en" o "de" tal área.
  %
  \director{Prof.}{}{}{Dr.} % Comentar esta línea si se tiene solo un director de tesis.
  \codirector{Prof.}{}{}{Dr.}  % Comentar estas líneas si no son necesarias.
  \directoracademico{Prof.}{}{}{Dr.}
  %
  \graduatename{Química}
  \institute{Facultad de Química}{FQ}  % La primer institución es la principal.
  \seconduniversity{} % Se agrega el nombre de otra universidad. Comentar esta linea si no es necesaria.
  \graduatelocation{}{}
  %
  \date{12}{06}{2018} % Fecha del documento: día/mes/año
  % Palabras claves en español
  %     
  \maketitle  % Comando que genera el título de la tesis.
  %

%  \listoffigures            % Lista de figuras
%  \listoftables             % Lista de tablas
%  \listadesimbolos          % Lista de símbolos
%  \listadenotaciones        % Lista de notaciones
%  \listadesiglas            % Lista de siglas
 \frontmatter  % Comando que genera la portadilla, el catalogo y el tribunal de evaluación. NO COMENTAR
  %
  \tableofcontents           % Tabla de contenidos. Compilar dos veces para ver los cambios completos.
  %
  \mainmatter % Comando que genera las listas y capítulos. NO COMENTAR
  %
  % Se incluyen los capítulos. Se pueden comentar los capítlos en los cuales no se está trabajando, para que el documento de trabajo sea más pequeño y compile más rápido.
  \include{capitulos/chap01} % Se carga el capítulo 01
  \include{capitulos/chap02} % Se carga el capítulo 02
  \include{capitulos/chap03} % Se carga el capítulo 03
  \include{capitulos/chap04} % Se carga el capítulo 04
 % Seguir copiando la linea de arriba para agregar más capítulos.
  \backmatter % Comando que generalos apéndices, anexos y bibliografía. NO COMENTAR

  \bibliography{bibliografia/biblio_3} % Agregar la cantidad de archivos .bib que se tengan para la bibliografía.
  \bibend % No comentar
  % 
  \glosario                  % Glosario, NO comentar
  %
  \apenarabicnumbering
  \apenmatter                % Apéndices, NO comentar
  \input{apendice/apendice_A}
  % Seguir copiando la linea de arriba para agregar más apéndices.
  %
 %\anexarabicnumbering
  %\anexmatter               % Anexos, NO comentar
 % \input{anexo/anexo_A}
  % Seguir copiando la linea de arriba para agregar más anexos.
  % 
\end{document}

% ===== FIN DEL DOCUMENTO =====
```

Comment: With `\include` there is inserted a `\newpage` for every chapter. You can use `\input`instead.

Comment: Sorry, your suggestion was not useful.

Comment: no one can run your example except you so it does not help understand your question. By default chapters always open on an odd numbered (rght hand page) so there will be a blank page if the previous chapter ends on an odd page. (I am guessing that that is what you mean by "blank space")

Comment: @dexteritas since `\chapter` always starts a new page, using `\include` has no effect on page breaking in this case.

Comment: you can use `[openany]` class option if you want to allow chapter opening on even pages (but there are some centuries of typesetting tradition that say you should not do that)

Comment: but I noticed that you are already using `oneside` so (assuming that option works as in the standard classes) all pages are typeset as odd pages and so chapters may start on odd or even sides and there should be no blank pages. Chapters start on a new page though.

Comment: Is there any news here?